# "Cascade" foreign keys through multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have 3 database tables: `Countries`, `Provinces` and `Cities`.

- `Countries` has `id` (PK) and `name`.
- `Provinces` has `id` (PK), `name` and `country_id` (FK).
- `Cities` has `id` (PK), `name` and `province_id` (FK).

My question is: would be good to have `country_id` too as FK in the `Cities` table? I mean, this `Country_id` would be `Provinces` table's FK (`Pronvices_Countries_id`), not `Countries` PK directly. My mate says it is better for performance. But having FK's of all previous tables may be tedious when you have a lot of tables. For example, having 8 tables in relation, the last one could have 8+ FK's instead of the last table PK as FK.

**Countries table:**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | France    |
+----+-----------+
```

**Provinces table:**

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | name      | country_id |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | Languedoc | 1          |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

**Cities table:**

```
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | name      | province_id | province_country_id |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Toulouse  | 1           | 1                   |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Can I have an explanation about this?

EDIT: Maybe the answer can be about identifying and non-identifying relationships? (I don't know.)

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the structure as simple as possible until it actually affects performance.

A big effort is made at the engine level to make use of indexes when making queries, so a best bet would be to **create indexes including all the fields you'll filter by**.

Otherwise, countries, provinces and cities look like small tables, so the total performance impact wouldn't be noticeable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This makes your inserts and updates more complicated and updates should definitely be handled with a trigger on all the  associated tables. That way if the country of the province changes, the country of cities in that province would also change automatically. You would also have to be careful that the source of the countryid value is consistent between the insert to province and the insert to city. You really have to be careful to maintain data integrity.

However there is a business case where it makes sense to do this.

That is:

- when the id is unlikely to change frequently (so little extra work normally on update would happen)
- when a significant portion of the queries against the child tables do
  not need any information from the intermediate tables
- and preferably when the descriptor information in the parent table is
  not usually needed.

For instance, we do this for clientid as the client never changes in our system.  almost all queries of subordinate tables need to be filtered by client but the client name is rarely needed in the end query. By cutting out several layers of joins to things we don't need in most queries, denormalizing clientid made sense.

However, in your case, while the first condition is likely met, are you really going to filter by country and not need province or city? I would find this a less likely scenario. Of course I am not familiar with how your data is used; it could be I am mistaken in this. I think in this case teh risk to data integrity woudl be higher than teh gain by doing this.